# TV screen goes black momentarily when a fan turns off - why?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-engineering

I am a physics major teaching in a classroom when a students turns off a regular pedestal fan - at the same instant, the TV screen at the front of the classroom goes black for a couple of seconds. I - and my students - are wondering why this is.

I have little experience in electrical engineering but I think I can understand that the phenomenon could occur if the fan was turned on - the capacitors would could momentarily draw in a power spike, thus limiting the power that goes into the TV. However, why would it happen when the fan is turned off? Does the opposite happen - that is, does the TV momentarily receive extra power and turns itself off as a protective measure?

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but what sort of screen is it?  Modern LED or old fashioned CRT?

Comment: Just like there can be a momentary voltage drop in a circuit when an appliance is turned on, there can be a momentary voltage jump when an appliance is turned off. That establishes the causal link for what you're seeing. As for why your particular fan and TV result in such dramatic behavior when the fan is turned off, the only way to determine that is to dig into the details of your particular fan and TV. The classroom circuit itself may also be a factor, particularly if it is old or is being heavily loaded.

Comment: @bob.sacamento it is a modern LED screen. An Apple TV, in fact.

Comment: @user35897  Well, old fashioned CRTs can be influenced by external E&M waves.  The trajectories of the electrons traveling through the vacuum tube can be affected.  But I guess that's the end of that theory.  Hope you get an answer.  This is an interesting problem!